# Конвертировать код из jquery в native js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ниже приведен код для изменения классов элементов по нажатию на ссылку `a` с классом `.catalog-item__back`. Естественно этих ссылок много как и элементов с классами `.catalog-item__content` и `.catalog-item__list`  и я не знаю как это переписать на native js.

```
$(".catalog-item__back").each(function (i) {
  $(this).on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".catalog-item__content")
      .eq(i)
      .toggleClass("catalog-item__content_active");
    $(".catalog-item__list").eq(i).toggleClass("catalog-item__list_active");
  });
});
```

Вот пытался перенести на джс:

```
document.querySelector(".catalog-item__back").each(function (i) {
    document.querySelector(this).addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document
        .querySelector(".catalog-item__content")
        .eq(i)
        .classList.toggle("catalog-item__content_active");
      document
        .querySelector(".catalog-item__list")
        .eq(i)
        .classList.toggle("catalog-item__list_active");
    });
  });
```

Как это запихнуть в событие клика на элемент, чтобы оно сработало?

Comment: Берёшь гайд  https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/  и  https://github.com/camsong/You-Dont-Need-jQuery  и пробуешь

Comment: Плюс открываешь доки по jquery - смотришь что должна делать каждая функция в твоём коде и потом в поиске вбиваешь наименование того же самого на нативном js

Comment: Я уже конвертировал онлайн, сути не поменяет ибо нужна общая картина, а используя доки соло я не смогу все соединить воедино.

Comment: если не знаете как, стоит изучить основы js, или нам написать код?

Comment: @Jean-Claude проблема в том что я не понимаю как это реализовать в функцию чтобы это сработало. Мне добавить код на джс, который я попытался сделать?

Comment: естественно надо добавить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По JQ коду, аналог на JS должен быть такой:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-item__back').forEach(function(elem, i) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-item__content')[i].classList.toggle('catalog-item__content_active');
    document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-item__list')[i].classList.toggle('catalog-item__list_active');
  });
});
```

Но что-то закрадываются смутные сомнения

Comment: Лучший, спасибо, все работает!